# getline() no instance of overloaded function c++

Tags: function, instance, cin, getline

trying to code a cin.getline function and it throws me an error saying theres no instance of overloaded function? I'm sure im using the parameters correctly, not sure how to fix..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include "NonPerishable.h"
#include "Item.h"
using namespace std;
namespace sict {
    class NonPerishable : public Item{

        fstream& save(std::fstream& file)  const {
            file << "N," << sku() << "," << name() << "," << cost() << "," << taxed() << "," << quantity() << endl;
            return file;
        }

        fstream& load(std::fstream& file) {
            char sku1[15];
            cin.ignore(2);
            cin.getline(sku1, 15, ',');

            //edit:
            double integer;
            cin.getline(integer, 15, ',');
        }
        ostream& write(std::ostream& os, bool linear) const {

        }

         istream& read(std::istream& is) {


        }
        fstream& save(std::fstream& file){

        }
    };
}
```

any help would be appreciated !

Edit: i fixed it for retrieving chars, but doubles/int wont work?

Answer (score 0):

The third argument is supposed to be a char, so try single quotes:

```
cin.getline(sku1, 15, ',');
```

Comment: For some reason, i cant use a double but rather only char?
edited main post